# Insert a line after a certain number of rows in datagrid in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

Is there a way to insert a horizontal line after a certain number of rows, which may be variable depending upon a property in data provider of a datagrid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach might be custom renderer, which will draw lines at bottom of cell based on data.

Comment: Yes but I was looking for a simpler approach (may be) - Can't I set the border property of a cell based on data? That way I could simply change the bottomBorder of the cells of the row I want to unline. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Maybe subclassing DataGrid can help, although it may be no simpler. There are functions like `drawLinesAndColumnGraphics`, which draw those lines.

Answer (score 0):

A custom cellRenderer is the only way I can think of.

This is pretty much the definitive resource I have found on dataGrids.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/datagrid_pt3.html